# Tangent lines from a fixed point to riemann surface is a subvariety of dimension 2.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Please, I appreciate any suggestion or reference to prove if statements 1 and 2 are true, according to the following hypothesis:

Let $M$ be a curve (compact riemann surface of genus $g \geq 2$) in a projective space $\mathbb{P}^k$, $k>3$. Let $x$ be a point in $\mathbb{P}^k\setminus M$. Then:

1. The tangent lines to $M$, that pass through $x$, form a sub-variety of $\mathbb{P}^k$ of dimension 2.
2. The lines that intersect $M$ in two points, that pass through $x$, form a sub-variety of $\mathbb{P}^k$ of dimension 3.

Comment: You are off by one dimension in both 1 and 2. Typically, for one, you get dimension one and for 2 you get dimension 2.

Comment: Yep, the standard way to do this is to consider incidence varieties like $M\times \mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^k$ where the image is the set of all tangent lines to $M$.